# Similarity of any matrix with complex entries

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone give a matrix $M \in M_3(\mathbb{C})$ with trace zero such that $M$ is not similar to any skew symmetric matrix. 
 
My attempt: 
 the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p_A(\lambda)=-\lambda\bigl(\lambda+\mathrm i\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\bigr))\bigl(\lambda-\mathrm i\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\bigr),$ where $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&a&b\\-a&0&c\\-b&-c&0\end{bmatrix},$$hence the JCF of $A$ is $\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\0&-\mathrm i\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}&0\\
0&0&\mathrm i\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}
\end{bmatrix}$. From here i don't know how to proceed. 
 
 Any help would be appreciated thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A complex square matrix is similar over $\mathbb C$ to a complex skew-symmetric matrix if and only if its Jordan form is a direct sum of odd-sized nilpotent Jordan blocks and pairs of Jordan blocks of the form $\{J_k(\lambda),J_k(-\lambda)\}$ (cf. theorem 1.2.5 of Olga Ruff's [master thesis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.146.5519&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).

Hence $A=J_2(0)\oplus0$ is not similar over $\mathbb C$ to any complex skew-symmetric matrix. Obviously, it is also not $\mathbb R$-similar to any real skew-symmetric matrix, because it is nilpotent but nonzero.

You may also directly prove that our example $A$ is not similar to any skew-symmetric matrix by showing that
$$
\pmatrix{0&a&b\\ -a&0&c\\ -b&-c&0}\pmatrix{0&a&b\\ -a&0&c\\ -b&-c&0}
=\pmatrix{-(a^2+b^2)&-bc&ac\\ -bc&-(a^2+c^2)&-ab\\ ac&-ab&-(b^2+c^2)}
$$
is zero if and only if $a=b=c=0$.

Comment: Can i take $M=J_3(0)$ which is not similar to any skew symmetric matrix since the JCF is not the same?

Comment: @EvaristeGalois No, $J_3(0)$ is by itself a nilpotent Jordan block. It is $\mathbb C$-similar to a complex skew-symmetric matrix according to Olga Ruff's result. However, you may pick $J_2(0)\oplus0$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have $\det(A)=0$ regardless of the values of $a,b,c$ (as the computation of your characteristic polynomial shows; also one has $(c,-b,a)\in\ker(A)$), so it suffices to take any invertible matrix with zero trace. For instance a diagonal one with diagonal entries $1,2,-3$, but I trust you can come up with other examples.